When compiling an Angular 17 project with ng build, I encountered an error
.form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
this is my angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "lib-mgmt-app-v2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "aos",
              "bootstrap",
              "rxjs",
              "sweetalert2",
              "zone",
              "tslib"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/lib-mgmt-app-v2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css",
              "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css",
              "node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js",
              "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1000kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "8kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "lib-mgmt-app-v2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "lib-mgmt-app-v2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "lib-mgmt-app-v2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

This is package.json
{
  "name": "lib-mgmt-app-v2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "ngx-typed-js": "^2.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

